# HTML table headers not aligning

Tags: html, html-table

I inherited an application from the previous company to maintain it; little or no transition documentation.  I have a screen that displays a table.  I was able to align the headers up on my Development system by changing the alignment to left.  When I promote it up to Production, everything is still bunched up on the left like it was prior to my fixing it.  I have checked, and my latest code is up there.  My ColdFusion skills are amateur at best. It appears correctly on one machine and not on the other. What am I missing?

```
<head>
<style>
body {margin-top:0; margin-bottom:0;}
table.wrapper {width:780; background-image:"../images/white7.jpg"; border:0;}
table.main {width:780px; background-image:"../images/white7.jpg"; text-align:left; border-color:#FFFFFF}
.center {text-align:center;}
.title {font: bold 12pt Arial; color: darkblue;}
tr.headings {font: bold 8pt Arial; color: #000080; background-color:#CCCCCC; vertical-align:baseline; height:17;}
.button-normal { background-color:#ffffcc; font: bold 8pt; color:#000080; border-left:0px; border-top:0px; padding-left:10px; padding-right:10px; height:18px; cursor:pointer; cursor: hand;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table class="wrapper">
  <tr>
    <td class="center"><span class="title">Stuff</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><table class="main" frame="void" rules="rows" align="left" cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 border=1>
        <tr>
          <td colspan=6></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="headings">
          <td colspan="6" class="left">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <span style="width:80px">Col1Top<br>Col1Bot</span> 
            <span style="width:90px">Col2Topp<br/>
            Col2Bot</span> <span style="width:100px">Col3Top<br/>
            Col3Bot</span> <span style="width:100px">Col4Top<br/>
            Col4Bot FY</span> <span style="width:90px">Col5Top<br/>
            Col5Bot</span> <span style="width:50px">Col6Top<br/>
            Col6Bot</span> <span style="width:50px">Col7Top<br/>
            Col7Bot</span> <span style="width:80px">Created<br/>
            by</span> <span style="width:80px">Created<br/>
            Time</span> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan=6><IFrame name="IFrame1" 
                            <cfoutput>
                                src="StuffConfig_detail.cfm<cfif isdefined('url.menu')>?menu=config</cfif>"
                            </cfoutput> 
                            width="100%" height="330px" frameborder="no" scrolling="Yes"> </IFrame></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td valign=top colspan=4 >
          <td valign=top align=right colspan=2><cfif #session.logID# eq "bmt.admin" >
              <input type=button onClick="javascript:top.leftFrame.document.location='StuffConfig_New.cfm<cfif isdefined('url.menu')>?menu=config</cfif>'" class="button-normal" value="Add New Stuff" >
            </cfif>
            <input type=button onClick="javascript:top.leftFrame.document.location='<cfif isdefined("url.menu")>Stuff_Manage.cfm?page=2005<cfelse>stuffmain.cfm</cfif>'" class="button-normal" value="Exit" >
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe showing some of your code would be helpful?

Comment: I changed actual column, table, and module names... [link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3594970/Config.txt)

Comment: I added your code in your post so that then people will take a look. But your HTML is missing a few tags, and you aren't declaring `<!DOCTYPE>`

Comment: Thank you for adding.  As I said, my skills are weak, and I inherited this.  Will the missing tags and the declaration help fix my problem?  Sorry to be dense.

Comment: It could, but at the moment your HTML isn't valid. So consider fixing it. :)

Comment: From what I can see, this question has nothing to do with CF. Strictly HTML/CSS. You will get a better response from that area if you run the .cfm script on your machine. Then do a "view source" and paste the HTML/CSS code here.

Comment: Still can't figure out how to tag code.  It becomes unreadable. [link]https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3594970/Config.txt

Comment: Just paste the code, highlight it and click the code button in the tool bar ie `{}`. However, you are still not posting the generated **html** (it should not contain CFML tags).

Comment: So doing the view source, as mentioned above, cutting and pasting didn't do it?   In the meantime, it is appearing correctly.  I changed it and it appeared on my Development system.  When I kicked it over to Test, it didn't initially display correctly.  Now it does.  Not sure what is happening.  Thanx for the replies.

Comment: Well... we have an issue between IE and Firefox.  It displays correctly on IE but not on Firefox.   It just never ends...

Comment: I've just now gotten back to this issue.  It works fine in IE but not in Firefox.  We have been forbidden to use IE due to a security issue.  In Firefox it appears all bunched up on the far left of the header.   Thanx.